# Rails 3: Return JSON with a specific variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a method returning this:

```
  format.json  { render :json => @call, :include => :customer }
```

However, I want the `@call.created_at` to return as a more readable datetime.

How can I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in your model to prettify the time.

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  def formatted_time
    #Pretty time
  end
end

format.json  { render :json => @call, :include => :customer, :methods => :formatted_time }
```

Comment: shouldn't this work: def formatted_time
      this.created_at = this.created_at.strftime("%d--%m--%Y") 
  end ?

Comment: no just def formatted_time this.created_at.strftime("%d--%m--%Y") end